# How to run VMWare over Cluster of PCs?

Tags: cluster-computing, vmware, virtualization

Right now, I have two situations that I believe can be solved with the same solution:

- I want to run a Virtual Machine (VM) that needs at least 6 GB, but I only have 4 GB
- I want to create VMs for students on the faculty server, so they access it there. The problem is: we don't have faculty server.

I think a solution can be to have more than a single PC combined together as a cluster, then I create the VMs there. So, I guess my solution will consist of:

- Different PCs connected together through a network
- Some sort of software installed on the nodes. I think I might need to have a single node as a master or something.
- Hypervisor is installed over that software to give me ability to create the virtual machines.

I am sure that VMWare is the solution I am looking for, but I am not sure where to start. Please consider helping me with this issue as soon as possible. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [SF]"

Comment: Thanks for directing me to those two sites. Apologies for any inconvenience I might have caused.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the closest thing to what you are asking is a high availability cluster. unfortunately this does not solve your needs as the point of a high availability cluster is to have a machine to take over if something catastrophic happens to another - it does not distribute workloads.

As far as I know there are no hypervisors that support cluster computing, and even if there were, having an operating system running where there is 4 gigs of ram on one machine, and 2 gigs on another would have massive performance implications (eg, every operation becomes dependent on network performance).

My best advice to you is to spend the money you would of spent on a hypervisor, and spend it on RAM instead.